# Share streaming video URL in android via ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, video, youtube, sharing

I need to share a video URL (not YouTube's) through a 3rd party application like Youtube, Gmail, etc. I have a link to a .mp4 or .m3u8 file on my server and I show it on a VideoView succesfully but I also have a sharing button on same activity which I would like to share as a link via ACTION_SEND.

I tested:

```
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(mVideoUrl));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Video"));
```

And it does launch a sharing chooser but I can't share this on Youtube, since they are expecting to receive a video type and not a link. Also sharing a link is a bad option since it does not consider it as a video what-so-ever.

If I use this:

```
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("video/*");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(filePath));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Video"));
```

While filePath is the absolute path of a video file stored in external storage, it does share a real video file on YouTube, Gmail, Facebook, etc.

But my problem is that I could have a video file size of more than 300MB, so downloading the file to the device and then sharing might be memory consuming and of course the downloading of the file takes some serious time.

So is there a way to share a link and let the 3rd party application consider as a video and embed it in their application or my only options is to download the video, save in storage and then share (which is the worse option) or to share it as a text link ?

Is there another option which I'm not familiar of to share streaming video via YouTube, Gmail, etc without download the real file to device ?